# How can the PR builds have independent build number formats compared to CI builds?

Tags: azure, build, azure-devops, numbers, pull-request

I want to have independent versioning for Pull Request builds on Azure DevOps. I can set the build number format for the build pipeline but not specifically for the PR's. Because of this, my build number for my CI builds is going up when a PR build is also kicked off. It would be great for someone to tell me how to add specific PR build numbers to separate these from my production CI builds.

Is this possible?

I've tried to look for PR build specific options in the configuration for the build pipeline but can't see it, maybe I am missing something.

E.g of CI build format: 1.0.2
E.g of desired Pull Request format: 1.0.2-PR-{PRNUMBER}